# NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Tags: reactjs, testing, next.js, react-testing-library, next-router

I got this error when testing with react testing library with jest. Anyone help me to do it.

I want to rectify this error and run the test. The error pointed to the code which I was testing. I should not do any corrections in the  code need to be test. I just need to correct in the testing code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.